# matplotlib.show does not show figure in console mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, console, pycharm

I am trying to plot my data with **matplotlib** in pycharm but if I execute the script in the console the `plt.show()` doesn't work. It only shows a white figure window with the hourglass coursor and when I close it it says 'program has stop working'

[image]

Also the first time I execute the code `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, the error message `Matplotlib support failed` appears. The second time it works fine and if I run it in run or debug mode it does show the plot. I don't understand what's going on here. I am using python 3.6

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000108710-Matplotlib-support-failed
People either rolled back to matplotlib 2.1.2 or possibly updated their Pycharm to version 2018.1.2

Comment: thanks a lot - rolling back to 2.1..2 works!